# invalid input syntax for integer: "1" postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

PostgreSql gives me this error when i try to cast a TEXT colum to a integer.

```
select pro_id::integer  from mmp_promocjas_tmp limit 1;
```

This colum contains only digits, valid integer. How can "1" be invalid integer?

```
select pro_id, length(pro_id) ,length(trim(pro_id)) from mmp_promocjas_tmp limit 1;
```

outputs:

```
1 | 2 | 2
```

Query `select pro_id  from mmp_promocjas_tmp where trim(pro_id) = '1'` shows nothing.

I tried to remove whitespaces, without no result:

```
select pro_id  from mmp_promocjas_tmp  where  regexp_replace(trim(pro_id), '\s*', '', 'g')
```

Comment: Attach query that is giving you the error. What datatype is column `pro_id`? Could you list also `length(pro_id)` ?

Comment: Is `pro_id` equal to `'1'` or `'"1"'`? And what is the exact error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably spurious invisible contents in the column. 
To make them visible, try a query like this:

```
 select pro_id, c,lpad(to_hex(ascii(c)),4,'0') from (
      select pro_id,regexp_split_to_table(pro_id,'')  as c
       from (select pro_id from mmp_promocjas_tmp limit 10) as s
 ) as g;
```

This will show the ID and each character its contains, both as a character and as its hexadecimal code in the repertoire.

Comment: Problem affected only the first row (imported from csv) so I updated value to '1' and it worked.  I can't really check if your solution helps, but I presume so.